# Handling dataskew without salting the join key in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to inner Join a million rows  dataframe with a 30 rows dataframe and both the tables have same join key, spark is trying to perform sort merge join and due to which all my data ends up in the same executor and Job never finishes, for example

```
DF1(million rows dataframe registered as TempView DF1)
+-------+-----------+
|   id  |  price    | 
+-------+-----------+
|    1  |   30      |
|    1  |   10      |
|    1  |   12      |
|    1  |   15      |
+-------+-----------+
```

```
DF2(30 rows dataframe registered as TempView DF2)
+-------+-----------+
|   id  |  Month    | 
+-------+-----------+
|    1  |   Jan     |
|    1  |   Feb     |
+-------+-----------+
```

I tried following

**Broadcasting**

```
spark.sql("Select /*+ BROADCAST(Df2) */ Df1.* from Df1 inner join Df2 on Df1.id=Df2.id").createTempView("temp")
```

**Repartitioned**

```
Df1.repartition(200)
```

Query Execution Plan

```
00 Project [.......................]
01 +- SortMergeJoin [.............................],Inner
02    :- Project [.............................]
03    :  +-Filter is notnull[JoinKey]
04    :    +- FileScan orc[..........................]
05    +-Project [.............................]
06      +-BroadcastHashJoin [..........................], LeftOuter, BuildRight
07        :- BroadCastHashJoin [......................],LeftSemi, BuildRight
```

Output of the number of partitions

```
spark.table("temp").withColumn("partition_id",spark_partition_id).groupBy
("partition_id").count
+-------+---------------+
|    21 |300,00,000     |
+-------+---------------+
```

Even though i re-partition/broadcast the data, spark is bringing all the data to one executor while joining and data gets skewed at one executor. I also tried turning off the **spark.sql.join.preferSortMergeJoin** to false. But i still see my data getting skewed at one executor. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: What do you wanted to do after `join`? I mean how do use `month` column post join?

Comment: Does not strike me as much data.

Comment: @SomeshwarKale the output of this under goes further joining in the subsequent stages, currently job is stuck exactly at this stage

Comment: @sri, Can you try `def repartitionByRange(numPartitions: Int, partitionExprs: Column*): Dataset[T] = {` on the big dataframe using column id. Also if possible please put the `execution plan` for join. Wanted to check the type of join the spark is choosing internally.  one more que. Are you using hive metastore?

Comment: It's an unusual join is it not?

Comment: @thebluephantom you are right, that's an unusual join

Comment: @SomeshwarKale updated the question with the query execution plan and repartitionByRange  is still doing the sort merge

Answer (score 1):

Just doing it like this, it works fine. Data is as is, no partitioning as such.

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast
 // Simulate some data
 val df1 = spark.range(1000000).rdd.map(x => (1, "xxx")).toDF("one", "val")
 val df2 = spark.range(30).rdd.map(x => (1, "yyy")).toDF("one", "val2")
 // Data is as is, has no partitioning applied

 val df3 = df1.join(broadcast(df2), "one")  
 df3.count // An action to kick it all along

 // Look at final counts of partitions
 val rddcounts = df3.rdd.mapPartitions(iter => Array(iter.size).iterator, true) 
 rddcounts.collect
```

returns:

```
res26: Array[Int] = Array(3750000, 3750000, 3750000, 3750000, 3750000, 3750000, 3750000, 3750000)
```

This relies on default parallelism, 8 on a CE Databricks cluster.

Broadcast should work in any event as the small table is SMALL.

Even with this:

```
val df = spark.range(1000000).rdd.map(x => (1, "xxx")).toDF("one", "val")
val df1 = df.repartition(50)
```

It works in parallel with 50 partitions. This is round-robin partitioning meaning the cluster will get partitions distributed over N Workers with at least N Executors. It is not hashed, the hash is invoked by specifying a column causing skewness if all values same. I.e. the same partition on 1 Worker for all the data.

QED: So, not all working on only one Executor, unless you have only one Executor for the Spark App or hashing applied.

I ran afterwards on my experimental laptop with local[4] and the data was being serviced by 4 cores, thus 4 Executors as it were. No salting, parallel 4. So, it is odd you cannot get that, unless you hashed.

[image]

[image]

You can see 4 parallel Tasks and thus not all on 1 Executor if on a real cluster.

Comment: I am using spark sql route, rather than using the dataframe joins. Looks like catalyst optimizer is behaving little weird in my case.  My data had 30 spark.sql.shuffle.partitions and job gets literally struck at 30th task and rest of 29 finishes in a sec. I see in the UI that, all the data is getting shuffled to that particular executor and at one point i see OOM and job is getting killed.

Comment: u would gave to post full code but this is what i ran and i would advise

Comment: as you see, no such issue from my approach. success

Answer (score 0):

1. why dose all data move to one executor ? If you only have same
   id(id:1) in DF1 and use id to join DF2 . according the
   HashPartitioner the data with id=1 will always move together .
2. have you occur Broadcast join ? check it in spark UI

Comment: The problem here is how to make the data with the same key distributed across multiple executors, since data getting ballooned at the same executor will choke the executor and job will run into issues.

Comment: a  millions rows is nothing...not sure we can talk of choking realistically

Comment: @thebluephantom million rows are joined with 30 rows returns 30 million rows on the same executor.